# Bounded operator on a non-empty set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $S$ be non-empty set, and let $X$ be the vector space of bounded functions on $S$, subject only to the condition that it be a Banach space when $X$ is supplied with the supremum-norm. Suppose $f:S \to \mathbb{F}$ is a function such that $fg \in X$ for all $g \in X$. Then the multiplication operator $M_f:X \to X$, defined by $M_f(g)=fg(g \in X$) is bounded.

I do not ask for the proof of this theorem. I just wonder if we assume $X\neq \lbrace0\rbrace$,

*) Is it true that $f$ is necessarily bounded? That would certainly explain why $M_f$ is bounded.

*)Is the theorem still true if $X$ is not required to be complete?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{F}$ a field?

Comment: what does $fg\in X$ mean? certainly $f(g)$ is an element of underlying field and cannot be a function in $X$. How is it a function mapping $S$ to a subset of $\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: yes $\mathbb{F}$ is a field. @KellyMaggs

Comment: sorry I was wrong write $f: X \to \mathbb{F}$. I have edited it @user160738

Comment: Of course $f$ is bounded, because $g:S \to \mathbb{F}: s \mapsto 1$ is a bounded function and $M_f(g) =f$.

Comment: And what do you mean "if $X$ is not required to be complete"? Do you mean to consider some other norm where $X$ is not complete or some other space altogether?

Comment: if we consider another norm where $X$ is not complete @Demophilus

Comment: @MuhImran Do you have an example? I really don't see any other way to put a norm on this space unless your set $S$ has some more structure.

Comment: @Demophilus that's what i am looking for. since i got stuck as well trying find another norm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't think there's much to ponder here. Assume that $f$ is bounded. This inequality holds in total generality: 
$$
|f(s)g(s)|\le \sup_{s\in S}|f(s)|\sup_{\sigma\in S} |g(\sigma)|.$$ 
Using the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ notation we have 
$$
\|M_f(g)\|_\infty \le \|f\|_{\infty}\|g\|_{\infty},$$ 
which means precisely that the linear operator $M_f\colon X\to X$ is bounded and that its operator norm is smaller or equal to $\|f\|_{\infty}$.

For all of this to make sense we only need that $X$ be a *normed* space, which is always the case for any set $S$. (Actually, $X$ is always Banach, but that is not needed at this stage). Notice that, if $S\ne \varnothing$, you cannot have $X=\{0\}$. Indeed, if $s\in S$, you can define the functions 
$$\tag{1}
\lambda_s(\sigma)=\begin{cases} \lambda, &\sigma=s\\ 0, & \sigma \ne s,\end{cases}$$
where $\lambda\in \mathbb R$ is arbitrary. Since $\lambda_s\in X$, the space $X$ is strictly bigger than $\{0\}$.

Finally, you also ask whether the boundedness of $f$ is a necessary condition for the boundedness of $M_f$. The answer is affirmative. If $f\colon S\to \mathbb R$ is an unbounded function then there exists a sequence $s_n\in S$ such that $|f(s_n)|\to \infty$. Then 
$$
\|M_f(1_{s_n})\|_\infty \to \infty, $$
(where $1_{s_n}$ is defined in (1) with $\lambda=1$) and $\|1_{s_n}\|_\infty=1$. So $M_f$ maps a bounded sequence to an unbounded one, which means that $M_f$ is not bounded.

Comment: I don't see the reason yet why $X$ only need to be a normed space?

Comment: @lmhejhey: You only need the minimal structure to talk about bounded operators. You do not need completeness at this stage.